# What is installed with Java 7?

Tags: macos, java

Inspired by [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871702/java7-mac-os-x-file-name-encoding-with-special-characters), I noticed that my Java control panel reports that I have the latest version of Java installed (and I know that, because Safari is not blocking the plugin any longer), while the command line version seems to be different.

From Terminal:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_06-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_06-ea-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

Java 1.7.0_06 is not the latest version, as far as I know.

Hence my question:

If I install Java 1.7 from Oracle's web site and then rely on the "automatic" updating that it provides, will the command line version be stuck with the old version? A bit confused here.

Comment: Something odd in the setup here the default install gave me (build 1.7.0_13-b20) - as a check what does `which java` give?

Comment: @Mark `which java` gives `/usr/bin/java`, which is a symbolic link to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`. I imagine the old version I get on command line is the one I originally installed, while the one that the control panel refers to is the one that Safari uses. Still confused, though.

Comment: Sadly Java on OS X is a huge bag of hurt lately with all the updates, blocking, changes, who packages what and when. If it weren't for http://derflounder.wordpress.com I would just give up on anything needing java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Control panel in System Preferences refers to the Java Applet Plugin (JRE) that is made available to Safari and other browsers.

If you use the Help>Installed Plugins you should see a version signature if it is enabled The latest JRE reports

```
application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.7.0_13
```

The java you are looking at with java -version is the one installed with the full JDK. You  need to download the installer for that separately now from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
When installed java -version should report

```
java version "1.7.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```